# Universal Player Music com Web Services

Tags: android

Alguem já fez uma aplicação com um player de musica vindo de um webservices?

Estive pesquisando um e encontrei o android-UniversalMusicPlayer da Google open source, porem tem um trecho de código que não estou conseguindo adaptar para o meu proprio webservices

```
protected static final String CATALOG_URL = "http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json";
```

Esta linha que se encontra acima eu altero para minha propria URL, mas quando executo não aparece nenhuma musica, alguem conseguiu já fazer utilizando Retrofit?

Answer (score 1):

Hector,

Se você acessar a [url](http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json), vai ver como é feita a estrutura do Json que eles criaram.

Para que você somente mude a URL para o seu WebService, ele deve estar exatamente como está o criado pelo exemplo do Google.

Nele, existe uma chave chamada **music** que é um **array**:

```
{"music" : [ 
    { "title" : "Jazz in Paris",
      "album" : "Jazz & Blues",
      "artist" : "Media Right Productions",
      "genre" : "Jazz & Blues",
      "source" : "Jazz_In_Paris.mp3",
      "image" : "album_art.jpg",
      "trackNumber" : 1,
      "totalTrackCount" : 6,
      "duration" : 103,
      "site" : "https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music"
    }
]}
```

E dentro de cada laço do array, existe as informações referentes as músicas, você precisa ou deixar exatamente igual, ou mudar o parseamento do array de acordo com o seu Json.

Comment: Até esse ponto tudo bem consegui entender, a questão é que queria fazer com retrofit, e o webservices utilizo o CodeIgniter Restful, porém os resultados não obtive sucesso, e olha que estou seguindo o padrão desta estrutura json.